# ¿Cómo puedo extender la funcionalidad de django-registration-redux?

Tags: python, django, django-models, djangorestframework

¿Cómo puedo extender la funcionalidad de django-registration-redux
para que además de los campos clásicos de registro de usuario, me permita agregar campos adicionales de Perfil asociado a ese usuario?

Hasta ahora esto es lo que he hecho :

Este es mi models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from registration.signals import user_registered
from django.db import models

class Carrera(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Año(models.Model):
    año = models.CharField(max_length=15)

class Tipo_Curso(models.Model):
    tpc = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class UserEstudiante(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User)
   carrera = models.ForeignKey(Carrera)
   año = models.ForeignKey(Año)
   tpc = models.ForeignKey(Tipo_Curso)
```

esta es el form que eso:(aquí también tengo duda a la hora de hacer los campos ForeignKey)

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from django import forms
from lap_pds.models import UserEstudiante


class UserEstudianteForm(RegistrationForm):
    año=forms.Select()
    carrera=forms.Select()
    tpc=forms.Select()

class Meta:
    model=UserEstudiante
    fields='__all__'
```

esta es el url.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from registration.views import RegistrationView
from lap_pds.form import UserEstudianteForm

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=UserEstudianteForm), name='registration_register'),

   url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
              ]
```

Hago las migraciones y todo bien pero cuando entro a la url accounts/register me sale este error:

> AttributeError: type object 'UserEstudiante' has no attribute 'USERNAME_FIELD'

No entiendo si la clase User esta siendo referenciada no deberíaa tomar ese valor.